# How to append to first frame?

Tags: jquery, frames

I have the following code:

```
<frameset rows="70,*" frameborder="0" border="0" noresize="">
  <frame name="heading" scrolling="no" noresize="" src="head.htm" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
  <frame name="online" src="head/head/heading.htm" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
</frameset>
```

I have append to a div to the body first frame. How do I do that? I tried various solutions but still cant get to append my div.

Comment: _I tried various solutions_ Post them. Might this help `$('frame[name="heading"]').append()`

Comment: @Satpal already tried that. didnt work

Comment: frames are deprecated use iframe instead.

Comment: @C-link: cant do that. so still have to use frames.

Answer (score 0):

Frames are deprecated use iframe instead.

But if you don't use html5 and want to use frames, then you should care to append that frame inside frameset. Just appending it to the body won't work.

```
$('frame[name="heading"]').appendTo('#framesetId');
```

Comment: im not familiar with frames so can you provide some code for that?

Comment: What if frameset doesnt have any id?

Comment: you should have id or class for that frameset